# Using array param in array_walk callback

Tags: php

I have a CSV file. The first line contains header information.

Below is an excerpt of the file (comments added).

```
Name, City, State, Country // header line 
Tom, Jackson, Mississippi, United States // line 1
Simon, Temple, Pennsylvania, United States // line 2... etc...
```

I'm parsing this CSV into an array using array_map:

```
// parse CSV file into an array
$fileArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file["tmp_name"]));
```

Which gives me the following:

```
array(3) { 
  [0] => array(4) { 
    [0] => string(4) "Name" 
    [1]=> string(4) "City" 
    [2]=> string(5) "State" 
    [3]=> string(6) "Country" 
  } 
  [1] => array(4) { 
    [0] => string(4) "Tom" 
    [1]=> string(7) "Jackson" 
    [2]=> string(11) "Mississippi" 
    [3]=> string(13) "United States" 
  } 
  [2] => array(4) { 
    [0] => string(5) "Simon" 
    [1]=> string(6) "Temple" 
    [2]=> string(12) "Pennsylvania" 
    [3]=> string(13) "United States" 
  }
```

I'm trying to remap the array to key/value pairs, so that the key will reference the appropriate header field. So for example:

```
array(3) { 
  [0] => array(4) { 
    ['Name'] => string(4) "Name" 
    ['City']=> string(4) "City" 
    ['State']=> string(5) "State" 
    ['Country']=> string(6) "Country" 
  } 
  [1] => array(4) { 
    ['Name'] => string(4) "Tom" 
    ['City']=> string(7) "Jackson" 
    ['State']=> string(11) "Mississippi" 
    ['Country']=> string(13) "United States" 
  } 
  [2] => array(4) { 
    ['Name'] => string(5) "Simon" 
    ['City']=> string(6) "Temple" 
    ['State']=> string(12) "Pennsylvania" 
    ['Country']=> string(13) "United States" 
  }
```

I'm using array_walk to alter the array with a callback function, but it appears that array_walk is having problems processing an array as the 3rd argument.

```
// parse CSV file into an array
$fileArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file["tmp_name"]));

// header line
$header = $fileArray[0];    // header[0] = "[0]=>Name, [1]=>City... etc"

/*  alterArray
 *  Update the array to key/value
*/
function alterArray(&$item, $key, $prefix) {
    $item = "${prefix}[${key}]}: ${item}";
}

// use array_walks to
array_walk($fileArray, 'alterArray', $header);

// print result 
print_r($fileArray);
```

I'm getting this error:

`Notice: Array to string conversion`

Answer (score 1):

Each item in `alterArray` is an array, and you obviously try to cast it to string, which throws the error (just `var_dump` `$item` in `alterArray` to see it for yourself). What you want:

```
function alterArray(&$item, $key, $header) {
    $item = array_combine($header, $item);
}
array_walk($fileArray, 'alterArray', $header);
```